# Is Ivan 'Ironman' Stewart's Super Off Road the first game to implement paid upgrades?

Tags: gaming-history

I went to the arcade recently and played Ivan 'Ironman' Stewart's Super Off Road (long name) for the first time. I noticed you could put tokens in the machine with the purpose of buying upgrades for your truck. Is this the first game to implement this sort of thing? I can't find anything online that says otherwise.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, this isn't a problem you're facing with a game.  We try to keep questions as close to solving problems as possible.  Please see [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/how-do-we-feel-towards-specific-questions-about-the-history-of-a-certain-game-me) if you're looking for more information.  As such, I have voted to close this.

Comment: Voting to reopen since "what is the first X" seems to have become on-topic by later consensus since this question was closed, i.e [Which game first introduced the concept of weapon recoil?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362854/which-game-first-introduced-the-concept-of-weapon-recoil)